# Mailu : when I run docker-compose, I got this error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I made a fresh install of mailu and when I run docker-compose up -d I have the following message :

```
Starting mailu_resolver_1 ... error

ERROR: for mailu_resolver_1  Cannot start service resolver: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "proc" to rootfs at "/proc" caused: mount through procfd: permission denied: unknown

ERROR: for resolver  Cannot start service resolver: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "proc" to rootfs at "/proc" caused: mount through procfd: permission denied: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Do you know the cause of the issue ?

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Docker daemon has permissions problems. Check out: https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/main/docker-without-sudo.md

Comment: Found the issue. keyctl and nesting should be enabled on the LXC (proxmox)